# Compile simple C Bluez program withouth installed libraries

Tags: c, gcc, bluez

I have written a simple C program the performs an LEScan, which is present as a function in hcitools (Bluez). The following are my Bluez library includes, and all the function definitions are present in there:

```
//Bluez Libraries
#include "lib/bluetooth.h"
#include "lib/hci.h"
#include "lib/hci_lib.h"
```

My question is: When I compile, I have to include the installed bluetooth libraries. Is there any way around this? Could I compile without the need for the installed Bluetooth Libraries?

```
gcc main.c -lbluetooth -o exe/simpleScan
```

Thank you

Comment: If you don't call a bluetooth function, you don't need the library. But it seems you are calling a Blues function, so you need the library(ies).

Comment: None of the function definitions are present in the header files: just the *declarations*. The *definitions* are in the library.

Comment: That clarifies it up for me. Thanks alot!

Comment: If you don't want to use libbluetooth API's you can use bluez DBus methods to start LEScan. See doc/adapter-api.txt from bluez source. You can also do this using kernel bluetooth management sockets directly. See doc/mgmt-api.txt from bluez source directory.